# Display Different Tables onClick

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

I have a couple different tables, all of which are built dynamically from a MySQL DB. I am wanting to be able to toggle between tables, it doesn't matter if I use tabs or buttons.

Here is my function to build my table:

```
function load_pending() {   


            $.post(
            "Returnsmedb.php",
            function (response) {

                var block = []

                index = 0;
                for (var item in response){

                    var objectItem = response[item];

                  var firstname = objectItem.fname;
                  var lastname = objectItem.lname;
                  var username = objectItem.uname;
                  var email = objectItem.email;
                  var deny = document.createElement("input");
                  deny.type = "checkbox";
                  deny.className = "chk";
                  deny.name = "deny";
                  deny.id = "deny";
                  var approve = document.createElement("input");
                  approve.type = "checkbox";
                  approve.className = "chk";
                  approve.name = "approve";
                  var moreinfo = document.createElement("input");
                  moreinfo.type = "checkbox";
                  moreinfo.className = "chk";
                  moreinfo.name = "moreinfo";


                    block.push(firstname);
                    block.push(lastname);
                    block.push(username);
                    block.push(email);
                    block.push(deny);
                    block.push(approve);
                    block.push(moreinfo);

                    dataset.push(block);
                    block = [];


                }


                var data = [" First Name", " Last Name "," User Name ", " Email "," Deny", "Approve", "More Information"]

                tablearea = document.getElementById('usersTable');
                table = document.createElement('table');
                thead = document.createElement('thead');
                tr = document.createElement('tr');

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var headerTxt = document.createTextNode(data[i]);
                    th = document.createElement('th');
                    th.appendChild(headerTxt);
                    tr.appendChild(th);
                    thead.appendChild(tr);
                }

                table.appendChild(thead);



                for (var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
                    tr = document.createElement('tr');
                    tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
                    tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
                    tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
                    tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
                    tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td')); 
                    tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
                    tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));


                    tr.cells[0].appendChild(document.createTextNode(dataset[i][0]));
                    tr.cells[1].appendChild(document.createTextNode(dataset[i][1]));
                    tr.cells[2].appendChild( document.createTextNode(dataset[i][2]));
                    tr.cells[3].appendChild( document.createTextNode(dataset[i][3]));
                    // tr.cells[4].appendChild( document.createTextNode(dataset[i][4]));
                    tr.cells[4].appendChild((dataset[i][4])); //
                    tr.cells[5].appendChild((dataset[i][5])); //
                    tr.cells[6].appendChild((dataset[i][6])); //
                    table.appendChild(tr);                   
                }
                tablearea.appendChild(table);


            }, 'json'
        );           
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div id="wrap">

        <br />
        <br />
            <h3>User Maintenance | Pending User Requests</h3>
        <h4 class="welcome"></h4>
        <hr /> 
        <div class="colWrap">
            <input type="button" id="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="deny(); approve(); info();"> 
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="call some function">Pending Users</button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="call some function">Awaiting Reply</button> 
        </div>


    <input type="button" id="deny" value="Deny" onclick="deny()"> <input type="button" id="Approve" value="Approve" onclick="approve()"> <input type="button" id="info" value="More Information" onclick="info()"> -->

            <br />
            <br />

            <div class="col1">
    <!-- <div id = "thead"></div>    -->
    <div id="usersTable" class="tabcontent">
    <div id="replyTable" class="tabcontent">  

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
```

I was hoping I could just have a button call a function and make one table display and then hide the other but it doesn't seem to work. What's the easiest way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You HTML is cut...

Comment: I added in the top body tag. Everything above it is not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using JQuery, similar to the other answer but there were some differences. The if statement in the other seemed to be throwing things off but his answer pointed me in the right direction.

Here is my HTML.

```
<div class="colWrap">
            <input type="button" id="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="deny(); approve(); info();"> 
            <button id="p_users"></button>
            <button id="msg_sent"></button> 
        </div>

            <br />
            <br />

            <!-- <div class="col1"> -->
            <div id="usersTable"  ></div>
            <div id="replyTable"  style = "display: none;"> </div> 

    <!-- </div> -->


    </div>
```

And my beloved JQuery.

```
$(function () {
    $("#msg_sent").click(function () {
        var table = document.getElementById("replyTable");
        $('#usersTable').hide('slow');
        $('#replyTable').show('slow');
         console.log(table);
    });
});
$(function () {
    $("#p_users").click(function () {
        var table = document.getElementById("usersTable");
        $('#usersTable').show('slow');
        $('#replyTable').hide('slow');
        console.log(table);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some jquery to hide and show the tables on a button click.

```
$(function () {
        //Create a click function on whatever button you want to show and hide the tables with
        $("#ShowHideTablesButton").click(function () {
            var $Table1 = $("#Table1_ID");
            var $Table2 = $("#Table1_ID");

            //If table 1 is hidden, then show it and hide the other table or vise versa
            if ($Table1.hasClass("hidden")) {
                $Table1.show();
                $Table2.hide();
            }
            else {
                $Table2.show();
                $Table1.hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

You can see a working example of something like this here: [show/hide example](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show)

You could also just populate the tables inside of tabs.

```
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="showHideTable(event, 'Table1')">table1</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="showHideTable(event, 'Table2')">table2</button>
</div>

<div id="Table1" class="tabcontent">
   <table>
       <!--Content..-->
   </table>
</div>

<div id="Table2" class="tabcontent">
    <table>
        <!--Content..-->
    </table>
</div>
```

You can see a working example of tabs here: [tabs example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp)